# How do I set the development environment for Requests contribution?

Tags: python, python-requests

The `requests` docs are asking questions be asked on StackOverflow with the matching tag. Please excuse me if this is inappropriate use of the site.

I would like to contribute a few lines of code to `requests`. I have forked the repository, cloned it to my machine and so on.

However, I am missing the standard way to set up my `virtualenv` ready for `requests` development. Haven't found anything in the docs (and please correct me if I'm mistaken).

Usually there would be a `requirements.txt` file, which I would `pip install -r` with. But this doesn't seem to be the case with this project.

Please point me in the right way to go about this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Requests' main author Kenneth Reitz is also an author of pyenv, a newer tool than pip. Naturally requests uses pipenv to resolve dependencies:

```
pipenv install requests
```

The replacement for `requirements.txt` is `pipfile` and `pipfile.lock`.